# Is there a limit to the number of naturally-spawned wolves you can have?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering if there was a limit to the amount of wolves you can have in Minecraft. I have seen a lot of videos of people with a lot of wolves. Just wondering how because there *is* a limit to the number of mobs that can spawn around you. I would like to know if everything written here can be done legit.

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit to the amount of wolves you can have at a time **tamed**. However, there is a limit of about 6 wolves that can be naturally spawned in a about 30 block radius **untamed**. This also applies to hostile mobs.  Passive mobs (like cows, sheep, etc.) have a different spawn limit. For more information, see ["Spawning" on the "Wolf" page at Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wolf#Spawning).